# NoSQL and REST web-services

Tags: xml, json, rest, nosql, jersey

I understand that if you use SUN's Jersey REST implementation framework, you get the ability to use XML and JSON doc's interchangably. I've tried this in a simple REST service and it works just fine, marshalling XML or JSON to Java objects and back again without any problems.

My Question is this.....

***Whats the simplest 'NoSQL' way to persist these Java object's?***

I have a JPA solution already that works really well - its OO and I can use the same Java objects for marshalling/persistence, but I'm interested if a NoSQL database will give me an even simpler more scalable document-centric mechanism for saving my entities in persistent storage?

Suggestions with windows friendly NoSQL or embedded in JVM NoSQL would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like maybe [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) or [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) could do the trick?

Also, there are also few other questions related to NoSQL (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875432/use-cases-for-nosql), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745911/nosql-databases)) that contain some more information about NoSQL databases and might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I've gone with CouchDB and the Ektorp Java lobrary in the end - thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I cloud help :)

Answer (score 1):

BDB or any other key-value db will do (like simple gdbm).

http://aurora.regenstrief.org/~schadow/dbm-java/db-2.4.14/man/man.html/index_java.html

Answer (score 0):

Save the XML to disk?  NoSQL, No Database, Perfect.

Comment: It's not mentioned in the question, but I assume that @benwilcock needs to support some sort of multi-user environment, since he's talking about databases. Unless we're talking about some sort of network share, then I guess saving to disk won't do :p

Comment: Mutli-user systems do not always require databases, every time. Sometimes the simplest approach wins, or at least deserves consideration.  I'm not going to guess at the requirements of a 18 month old question.