# Should I use SQL or JSON

Tags: sql, json, database

On my website I have quite a few JSON databases that I use to store info, such as comments. I know SQL but find it much easier to use JSON for me. Even though I like JSON a lot should I try and switch over to using SQL?

Comment: You should definitely try to learn SQL so you know both and when one is a better fit.

Comment: I do know both but when would I use SQL instead of JSON?

Comment: That's a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875432/use-cases-for-nosql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't make JSON document too large, MongoDB has limit of 16MB and even that is quite large. Reading a JSON document typically requires reading the entire thing into memory, which not only uses memory but takes CPU time. Also, you can't do granular locking within a JSON document.

Therefore you should have some system, for organizing JSON documents, which could be (but not limited to):

- the filesystem
- MongoDB
- PostgreSQL

PostgreSQL is now being preferred by many to MongoDB, you can have SQL queries for you relational structures and mix in JSON documents where needed. PostgreSQL even has [JSON types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html).