# Is laravel production ready?

Tags: php, laravel, production-environment, production

I have an ecommerce project to launch and I am thinking of using laravel. But my concern is as to whether

1. Is it production ready?
2. What db should it use in production? Mysql, Mongo db
3. How many users who can simultaneously access the 
   website without any performance issues? What

Any suggestion on the infrastructure to use is also welcomed thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1) Indeed it is: Laravel has been used in production environments for a long time. The 5.1 version is Long Term Support (LTS), so you'd probably better stick with it

2) The choice between a relational and a nosql database is not trivial. Chech [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875432/use-cases-for-nosql) post to see if it can help you. If it was to me: don't use a nosql db if the nature of your data is inherently relational, unless you have very good reasons to do it

3) Performance depends on your infrastructure, code efficency and traffic rate, so it's impossible to estimate without specific informations

Comment: I've used it for two days and already found this:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1186

Also crashes with MySQL and json fields for some reason.